# Setting up presto server on mac os locally not accessible in localhost

Tags: macos, presto

I followed the instructions to setup a server found in the link below:
https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html

However when I opened up localhost:8010, it says that the site can't be reached and there are no server logs that was appended or the launcher.log. I am not sure how I can successfully run presto server on a mac os locally

```
Environment:
-------------

MacOS - 10.13.6
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Any help or pointers would be great.

I have created the etc folder and here is what the configurations is set to:

```
config.properties
--------------------
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8010
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
query.max-total-memory-per-node=2GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=localhost:8010

--------------------

jvm.config:
--------------------
-server
-Xmx16G
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError
--------------------

log.properties:
-----------------
com.facebook.presto=INFO
-----------------

node.properties
-----------------
node.environment=production
node.id=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff
node.data-dir=/Users/temp/Desktop/presto/data
-----------------

catalog/jmx.properties
-----------------
connector.name=jmx
-----------------
```

After this is all set I started the server with the following command:

```
Stopped 5178
Started as 5665
```

Answer (score 0):

`discovery.uri` should be an URI, e.g. `http://localhost:8010`

To see launcher output, run `launcher run` instead of `launcher start`.

Related recommendations:

- for just playing with Presto, I can recommend Presto Docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/trinodb/trino
- for one-off troubleshooting kind of questions, which are unlikely to help others SO users, I recommend `#troubleshooting` channel on Presto Community Slack (https://trino.io/slack.html)

Comment: I have already tried setting `discovery.uri` to `http://localhost:8010` but I was experiencing the same issue

Comment: Starting the server in verbose mode `bin/launcher restart --verbose` I found out that it was using java to run the server in the background. The shell I was using was having trouble running java and once I switched to a different session I was able to get this up and running.

Comment: @sophist_pt thanks, i added suggestion to run `launcher run`.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced issues using MacOS Catalina and java 11: the trick is to add

```
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
```

in `jvm.config`. Please check here for more details  https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/752.

For the port just check with the browser that there is nothing connected to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` (you should get an error) and set `discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080` in `etc/config.properties`.